# autofs indirect mount in CentOS 7

Tags: mount, autofs

I am using CentOS7. I have tried to test "autofs". I have created 2 centos servers as cent_ldap and cent_client. I have configured cent_client to use ldap authentication successfully.
In cent_ldap I have created nfs export as

/home   *(rw)

Using cent_client I have created

mkdir /mnt/fordirect -p

mkdir /mnt/forindirect -p

In the file /etc/auto.master.d/direct.autofs -> /-  /etc/auto.direct

In the file auto.direct -> /mnt/fordirect -rw,sync cent_ldap:/home

In the file /etc/auto.master.d/indirect.autofs -> /mnt  /etc/auto.indirect

In the file auto.indirect -> forindirect -rw,sync cent_ldap:/home

systemctl restart autofs
autofs is started without any error

But when I test those mounts from root user

ls /mnt/fordirect --> user1 user2 user3

ls /mnt/forindirect --> #it didnt give any output

Can someone tell me why is there indirect mount didnt give any output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly (I find autofs powerfull but confusing) it should work like this:

In the file /etc/auto.master.d/indirect.autofs:

```
/mnt/forindirect /etc/auto.indirect
```

And in /etc/auto.indirect:

```
* -rw,sync cent_ldap:/home/&
```

Then test with:

```
ls -l /mnt/forindirect/user1 /mnt/forindirect/user2 /mnt/forindirect/user3
```

Comment: I followed your instructions, after all when I have run the command <br> ls -l /mnt/forindirect/user1</br> then it gives me  <br>ls: cannot open directory /mnt/forindirect/user1: Permission denied</br> but after i ran the command <br>ls -l /mnt/forindirect</br> it shows me full directory info

Comment: And it does not work?

Comment: after all when I have run the command <br> ls -l /mnt/forindirect/user1</br> then it gives me  <br>ls: cannot open directory /mnt/forindirect/user1: Permission denied</br> but after i ran the command <br>ls -l /mnt/forindirect</br> it shows me full directory info

Comment: So, running `ls -l` caused autofs to mount correctly, but the uid that was running `ls -l` has no permission on the mounted directory on the server.

Comment: when I creating/editing those auto.* files do I want to use tab key or space key. I previously use tab key.but i didnt got any output like this. but in your way I got the answer, thanks man

Comment: [root@cent_client ~]# ls -l /mnt/forindirect/

Comment: drwx------. 6 user1 user1 176 Oct  2 21:13 user1

Comment: drwx------. 5 user2 user2 107 Oct  2 12:25 user2